# Firebase crash with Dexguard

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, proguard, dexguard

Any idea why this crash might be happening? Debug build works, but Dexguard release crashes when trying to get signed in user (signed in using `signInWithCustomToken`)

***Update***: Following proguard setting fixed the issue

> -keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }

Firebase version: 9.4.0

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field o.ս.ʽ has type android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap, got o.dj
       at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaog$1.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaog$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamp.zza(Unknown Source:46000)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafy.zze(Unknown Source:8000)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaft.(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(Unknown Source:19000)
```

Proguard config:

```
# Firebase
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-keepresources string/default_web_client_id
-keepresources string/firebase_database_url
-keepresources string/gcm_defaultSenderId
-keepresources string/google_api_key
-keepresources string/google_app_id
-keepresources string/google_crash_reporting_api_key
-keepresources string/google_storage_bucket
# Supoort
-dontwarn android.support.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
```

Comment: Looks like a class in android.support is getting renamed. Try adding -keep class android.* * { *; }

Comment: Sorry, updated the post with support related proguard rules, which are already in place.

Comment: btw. you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Following ProGuard setting fixed the issue

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
```